# Word or phrase for postponing the inevitable

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase which means "postponing the inevitable"

Ex :

> "Doing this action is merely postponing the inevitable"
>
> "This action is _____"
>
> "Trying to stop me is only postponing the inevitable"
>
> "Trying to stop me is _____"

There are words like "futile" but it doesn't fit exactly.

Comment: Not really, like you want to delay a catastrophe but you know it's inevitable.

Comment: ['Stick one's head in the sand'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)

Comment: I have not come across such a word to describe that phrase. What is wrong with just saying "postponing the inevitable"?

Comment: What words or phrases have you considered, why didn't they 'fit exactly'?

Comment: An action can be described as **a stall** or **stalling**. There's also **prevarication**.

Comment: @Spagirl Words like "futile", "useless", "pointless", "vain" and other synonyms, but they lack the idea of delaying, postponing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe an event as **a stall** or as **stalling**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stall) offers the following definitions:

> **stall** *noun*
>
> - a ruse to deceive or delay
>
> **stall** *verb*
>
> - to play for time :  delay
> - to hold off, divert, or delay by evasion or deception

Comment: If you have synonyms or similar words, don't hesitate!

Comment: And where is in _stall_ the inevitability which you were talking about? There is nothing inevitable or inescapable in this word or in any of its synonyms.

Comment: @User26328, in a way it's absent ... however the word **stall** has no implication that it will **prevent** either. If an event is coming, then the stall will not alter that, it only changes the **when** of the event.

Comment: I prefer my original answer, but there are also the concepts of a **temporary reprieve** and a **stay of execution**.

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 I like _stall_ because it shows that the action is a mere pause, and it does not prevent anything in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the adjective [**doomed**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doomed), which refers exactly to the inevitability of an event.

> Likely to have an **unfortunate** and **inescapable** outcome; ill-fated.

Comment: It seems to describe more the finality, the unavoidable event than the action(s) trying to delay the said event.

Comment: ... Yes – it doesn't refer to delaying tactics at all.

Answer (score 0):

> **Stopgap**
>   [stop-gap]/
>   noun
>
> 1. something that fills the place of something else that is lacking; temporary substitute; makeshift.

"This action is only a stopgap." 
- implying that a more permanent solution is necessary to actually change the end result.

"Riding on a spare tire is only a stopgap. You will need to get a new tire if you want to drive your car much longer."